# File organization program

Tags: python

So I'm attempting to create a file sorting program using the shutil module

```
import glob, shutil, os, time, argparse


src='' 
dest=''
ext=''
extention = ''


def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Grab shell flags')
    parser.add_argument('--src', action="store", dest="src", type=str, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--dest', action="store", dest="dest", type=str, default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--ext', action="store", dest="ext", type=str, default=None)
    global src 
    global dest
    global ext

def if_parser_fails(source_directory, dest_directory, file_extentions):
    while source_directory is None:
            global src
            src = raw_input('What is the directory you wish to monitor?: ')
    while dest_directory is None: 
            global dest
            dest = raw_input('Where do you wish to move the files?: ')
    while file_extentions is None:
            global extention
            extention = raw_input('Please input the extension(s), seperated by commas, that you wish to use as criteria for sorting: ')


def sorter(source_directory, dest_directory, file_extentions): 
    found = glob.glob('%(src)s./*' % {"src": source_directory})
    ext_list = file_extentions.split(',')
    global moving_files
    moving_files = []
    for i in found:
            (filepath, filename) = os.path.split('%(file)s' % {"file": i})
    for h in filename:
            for j in ext_list:
                    if  j in h:
                            moving_files.append(h)
    else:
            pass

def copy_files(to_move, source_directory, dest_directory):
    for item in to_move:
            full_path = os.path.join(source_directory, item)
            full_path_dest = os.path.join(dest_directory, item)
            shutil.move(full_path, full_path_dest)
            print("%(file)s has been copied to %(dest)s" % {"file": i, "dest": dest_directory})

def log_writer():
    log_path = os.path.join(dest, 'log.txt')
    write_time = time.asctime()

    with open(log_path, 'ab') as logfile:
            logfile.write('%(filename)s has been moved \n %(time)s \n \n' % {"filename": filename, "time": write_time})
    print file(log_path).read()

def main():
    parser()
    if_parser_fails(src, dest, ext)
    sorter(src, dest, extention)
    copy_files(moving_files, src, dest)
    log_writer()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But shutil keeps raising the error:

```
    shutil.Error: `S` and `S` are the same file
```

I believe it has something to do with the input and output directory somehow not being assigned values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's useful to post the ENTIRE traceback, since the error message contains important information, such as line number and callstack.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without the complete traceback, but it looks like in this segement:

```
for i in found:
        (filepath, filename) = os.path.split('%(file)s' % {"file": i})
for h in filename:
        for j in ext_list:
                if  j in h:
                        moving_files.append(h)
```

You are only taking the last filename, and appending individual characters of that filename to moving files.

Instead try:

```
for i in found:
        (filepath, filename) = os.path.split('%(file)s' % {"file": i})
        for h in filename:
                for j in ext_list:
                        if  j in h:
                                moving_files.append(h)
```